# Replace white spaces with underscores within a file (bash)

Tags: linux, bash

I am currently writing a script that accesses another file using "mapfile" to put it into an array. However, the inputted file contains some white spaces, which the script reads as a new array entry.

How do I replace the white spaces with underscores within the body of the file I'm bringing in? I have only seen instructions for how to replace a file name, not what's within it.

Thank you in advance! Please let me know if you need any further clarification.

Comment: show your code. It sounds like a lack of quoting. Make sure you do `for line in "${lines[@]}"` instead of `for line in ${lines[@]}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given:

```
$ cat file
1 2 3 4
```

You can use `sed`:

```
$ sed 's/[[:space:]]/_/g' file
1_2_3_4
```

So then you can do:

```
$ mapfile -t arr < <(sed 's/[[:space:]]/_/g' file)
```

Answer (score 1):

with tr:

```
tr [[:space:]] '_' <filename
```